# Write to Azure SQL DB from AMLS pipeline

Tags: python, sql, azure-machine-learning-service

Is there a way to write data to an Azure SQL DB from a pandas dataframe in an Azure Machine Learning Service pipeline using the AMLS python SDK? I know I can input SQL data using  [register_SQL_ds()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.datastore.datastore?view=azure-ml-py#register-azure-blob-container-workspace--datastore-name--container-name--account-name--sas-token-none--account-key-none--protocol-none--endpoint-none--overwrite-false--create-if-not-exists-false--skip-validation-false--blob-cache-timeout-none--grant-workspace-access-false--subscription-id-none--resource-group-none-) and I can save output data as a TabularDataset using [OutputTabularDatasetConfig()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.output_dataset_config.outputtabulardatasetconfig?view=azure-ml-py), but how do I write back to an Azure SQL DB?

Ideally I would like to add new rows and update old rows in an Azure SQL table. But just being able to output the data into a temporary SQL table and doing the add/update step afterwards in SQL would work as well.

Comment: By “SQL db” do you mean: Azure SQL DB?

Comment: Yes, edited my question to make that clear!

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below DataTransferStep pointers.
Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-pipeline-steps/azureml.pipeline.steps.data_transfer_step.datatransferstep?view=azure-ml-py
Example: https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-data-transfer.ipynb

Note: When copying data to an Azure SQL Database, data will be appended to an existing table. We also expect the source file to have a header row and the names should exactly match with column names in destination table.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. However I want to export data to an Azure SQL DB that is stored in memory, not in another storage option. I would like to do something similar to what was available for AML Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/export-to-azure-sql-database.

Comment: Can you clarify why you think there isn't feature parity? IMHO using `DataTransferStep` to output to Azure SQL is equivalent to Azure ML Classic's "Export to Azure SQL Database".

Comment: My understanding is that the "export data" feature in AML Studio allowed you to save a pandas dataframe to an Azure SQL DB. DataTransferStep seems to only allow data movement between storage locations (not from a pandas dataframe in memory). Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: I get it now. Yeah I agree it would be convenient to not have to "materialize" (i.e. save it to csv) the pandas df before transferring to Azure SQL.